# Sections appears smaller than intended

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having an issue with HTML sections. As shown in the screenshot the blue spot are the sections and they should include the grey space. The white space is what lays inside the section tags in HTML.

The problem was discovered when trying to add some space between each section, but everything we tried it wouldn't do anything.

[image]

```js
/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

let mainNavLinks = document.querySelectorAll("nav ul li a");
let mainSections = document.querySelectorAll("main section");

let lastId;
let cur = [];

// This should probably be throttled.
// Especially because it triggers during smooth scrolling.
// https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#throttle
// You could do like...
// window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
//    _.throttle(doThatStuff, 100);
// });
// Only not doing it here to keep this Pen dependency-free.

window.addEventListener("scroll", event => {
  let fromTop = window.scrollY;

  mainNavLinks.forEach(link => {
    let section = document.querySelector(link.hash);

    if (
      section.offsetTop <= fromTop &&
      section.offsetTop + section.offsetHeight > fromTop
    ) {
      link.classList.add("current");
    } else {
      link.classList.remove("current");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    background-color: grey;
    /* this breaks position sticky in Firefox */
    /* overflow-x: hidden; */
}
header {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    background: #5D5C61;
    background-image: url("../Assets/Images/headerImage.jpg");
    image-resolution: 1200x1400;
    color: white;
    padding: 4rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Chivo';
    font-size: 22px;
}

header a {
    padding-right: 20px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: underline;
}


header h1 {
    color: #fb6542;
}



nav {
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: #37474F;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Only stick if you can fit */
@media (min-height: 300px) {
    nav ul {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
    }
}
nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li a.current {
    background: #51656E;
}
main {
    padding-top: -30px;
}
section {
    padding: 2rem;
    margin: 0 0 10% 0;
    background-color: lightblue;
    display: block;
}

footer {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    background: #252E39;
    padding: 5rem 1rem;
}

a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

main a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

a:hover {
    color: #6B7B83;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active {
    color: #6B7B83;
}

.socialIcon {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
}

#socialMedia {
    text-align: center;
}



.CALink:hover {
    color: #202F36;
}

.container {
    width: 70%; 
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
}

.control-group {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: left;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0.2, 0.2, 0, 0.2);
    padding: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 1%;
    align-items: center;
}

.containerRight {
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
}


.control-groupRight {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0.2, 0.2, 0, 0.2);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 4% 1% 1% 1%;
}

.navTitle {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.endOfModule {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.sectionHolder {
    width: 100%; 
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link href="CSS/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="CSS/linkHover.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet'>
        <link rel="icon" href="Assets/Images/faviconTTT.png"/>
        <title>Silverflame</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div id="socialMedia">
                <a href="https://github.com/jesper3005"><img class="socialIcon" src="Assets/Images/mark-github.svg" alt="logo" /></a>
                <img class="socialIcon" src="Assets/Images/twitterSVG.svg" alt="twitter logo"/>
            </div>

            <h1>SilverFlame</h1>
            <h5>Jesper Christensen</h5>

            <a target="headerLink" href="https://www.thesilverflame.dk/">Home</a>
            <a target="headerLink" href="https://www.thesilverflame.dk/CA.html">CA</a>  
            <a target="headerLink" href="">About</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>

        </header>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#section-1" class="navTitle">Module 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-2">Maven</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-3">Network and HTTP</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-4" class="endOfModule">JavaScript & CA1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-5" class="navTitle">Module 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-6">ORM with JPA</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-7">Rest webservices with JAX-RS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-8">JavaScript</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-9" class="endOfModule">CA2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-10" class="navTitle">Module 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-11">SYS 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-12">?</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-13" class="endOfModule">SYS 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-14" class="navTitle">Module 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-15">SPA with React (TBD)</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-16">React routing, Security and RN</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-17" class="endOfModule">CA3 (TBD)</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-18" class="navTitle">Module 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-19">Project - Week 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-20">Project - Week 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-21">Project - Week 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <main>

            <section id="section-1">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <h2>Module 1 - Maven, Test & Network</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section id="section-2">
                <div class="sectionHolder">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <h2>Maven</h2>
                            <div class="tooltip">
                                <a href="https://github.com/jesper3005/SimpleCalculatorTravisCi">Simple Calculator</a>
                                <span class="tooltiptext">Github link</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="containerRight">
                        <div class="control-groupRight">
                            <h5>Learning Goals</h5>
                            <a href="#"><img class="docsIcon" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/50/000000/google-docs.png" alt="google docs icon" /></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section id="section-3">
                <div class="sectionHolder">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <h2>Network & HTTP</h2>
                            <a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_JV7ePLSpxGAd9KqauESTYbdR13LuafNKiFN0RX0v8w/edit?usp=sharing">Exercises - Network stack</a>
                            <br>
                            <a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SwxIZBLPdN6pKXjm8CmRxFbxxzjaeRbbcIedUwlzk_I/edit?usp=sharing">Exercise HTTP</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="containerRight">
                        <div class="control-groupRight">
                            <h5>Learning Goals</h5>
                            <a href="#"><img class="docsIcon" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/50/000000/google-docs.png" alt="google docs icon" /></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section id="section-4">
                <div class="sectionHolder">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <h2>JavaScript and CA1</h2>
                            <a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/14yDqpX_GEHvCkXMBM7KOD8mjEM2eLSj8WJqsfdhxSso/edit#">The JS array</a>
                            <br>
                            <a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cd4-VI5rSGv5NL6YHk_JGjPJckOdnYeBqFL1J4Y9EtE/edit#">JavaScript Exercice 1</a>
                            <br>
                            <a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/13TM3p2zq4u3cieJtIYQTnQaN7gYspyk9EIYxX0D_JgA/edit">Course Assignment 1</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="containerRight">
                        <div class="control-groupRight">
                            <h5>Learning Goals</h5>
                            <a href="#"><img class="docsIcon" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/50/000000/google-docs.png" alt="google docs icon" /></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section id="section-5">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <h2>Module 2 - Webstack</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section id="section-6">
                <div class="sectionHolder">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <h2>ORM with JPA</h2>
                            <h2>Study Point Exercise 3 - JPA, JPQL and Testing </h2>
                            <h3>Part 1</h3>
                            <a href="https://github.com/jesper3005/JPADayOneExercise/tree/master">Exercise - JPA Entity Mappings - 1</a>
                            <br>
                            <a href="https://github.com/jesper3005/JPADayTreeExercise/tree/master">Exercise - Java Persistence - Querying - 3</a>
                            <h3>Part 2</h3>     
                            <a href="#">Studypoint part two</a>
                            <h3>Part 3</h3>
                            <a href="https://github.com/jesper3005/ExamPrepOneJPQL">Exam Preparation Exercise on relations and queries</a>
                            <br>
                            <a href="https://github.com/jesper3005/ExamPrepTwoJPQL">Exam Preparation Exercise on JPQL</a>
                            <br>
                            <a href="#">Object Relational Mapping and Inheritance</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="containerRight">
                        <div class="control-groupRight">
                            <h5>Learning Goals</h5>
                            <a href="#"><img class="docsIcon" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/50/000000/google-docs.png" alt="google docs icon" /></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section id="section-7">
                <div class="sectionHolder">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <h2>Rest webservices with JAX-RS</h2>
                            <p>Add content</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="containerRight">
                        <div class="control-groupRight">
                            <h5>Learning Goals</h5>
                            <a href="#"><img class="docsIcon" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/50/000000/google-docs.png" alt="google docs icon" /></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section id="section-8">
                <div class="sectionHolder">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <h2>JavaScript</h2>
                            <p>Add content</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="containerRight">
                        <div class="control-groupRight">
                            <h5>Learning Goals</h5>
                            <a href="#"><img class="docsIcon" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/50/000000/google-docs.png" alt="google docs icon" /></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section id="section-9">
                <div class="sectionHolder">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <h2>Course Assignment 2</h2>
                            <p>Add content</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="containerRight">
                        <div class="control-groupRight">
                            <h5>Learning Goals</h5>
                            <a href="#"><img class="docsIcon" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/50/000000/google-docs.png" alt="google docs icon" /></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section id="section-10">
                <div class="sectionHolder">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <h2>ORM with JPA</h2>
                            <p>Add content</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="containerRight">
                        <div class="control-groupRight">
                            <h5>Learning Goals</h5>
                            <a href="#"><img class="docsIcon" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/50/000000/google-docs.png" alt="google docs icon" /></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>


        </main>

        <footer>
            &copy;2022

        </footer>
        <script src="Assets/JS/hoverEffect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Assets/JS/frontpage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are applying a float to the container which takes the item out of the document flow. Consider using flexbox instead of floats for layout.

```css
.sectionHolder {
    width: 100%; 
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
}

.container {
    flex: 1 1 70%; 
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
}

.containerRight {
    flex: 0 0 20%;
    height: 20%;
    font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a well-known issue when working with floated content. The `height` of the `section` elements are not being properly calculated because the floated content is not in the normal document flow.

Add `overflow:auto;` to the `section` elements which should correct the issue by forcing the rendering engine to recalculate the `height` of the element and once it does that, it should recognize the child content and factor it in.

Here's [more on the issue](https://www.lockedownseo.com/parent-div-100-height-child-floated-elements/) and other solutions.